# How to make staggered bar chart with three factors?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I was wondering how I can make a bar chart in R that will have three different factors on each year? I would like to make these three factors 'overlapping' but staggered a bit and add percent indicators to the bars. I searched the Internet for an answer, but I wasn't able to find one.

This is what I'm looking for:
[image]

I hope that picture of a chart helps to clarify what I'm after.

Comment: if you got any help from answers acknowledge them please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late to this, but since it's quick...

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(year = rep(2010:2014, 3), group = rep(LETTERS[24:26], 5), value = rep(c(34, 41, 59), 5))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(year), y = value, fill = group)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = -0.5)) + 
    geom_text(aes(y = value - 2, label = value), position = position_dodge(w = -0.5))
```

Comment: Thank you user127649, this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015), gr = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"), val = c(100, 300, 400, 10, 20, 30))
ggplot(aes(x = factor(year), group = gr, y = val, fill = gr), data = df) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```